# Finding real and decimal numbers

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using xslt1.0 for my html to xml conversion.

```
<xsl:variable name="margin">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="number($margin)">
<xsl:message>Its number</xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

This is my template which satisfying the condition and displaying message.If the variable margin's value is 0.5, then the condition becomes false.

How to write the condition which matches for decimals too?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a simple and short solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="margin">0</xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="number($margin)">
       <xsl:message>Its number</xsl:message>
      </xsl:if> </xsl:template>

This is my template which satisfying the condition and displaying message.
If the variable margin's value is 0.5, then the condition becomes false.
```

This is simply not true. Tested with 9 different xslt processors (both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0), the above code doesn't produce any message. On the other side, Any numeric value, different from 0 produces the message.

**Explanation**:

Due to the fact that `number(0)` is `0`, and `boolean(0)` is `false()`, the test doesn't succeed .

**Solution**:

Use this XPath expression:

```
number($x) = number($x)
```

This expression evaluates to `true()` exactly when `$x` is a number and then it is equivalent to:

```
$x = $x
```

When `$x` is not a number, the XPath expression above evaluates to `false()` because it is equivalent to:

```
NaN = NaN
```

and by definition `NaN` is not equal to any other value, including `NaN` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (using MSXSL.EXE, which requires terminate="yes" on the message in order to see its output) and found, as I expected, the opposite to be true.  When $margin is zero, the "if" doesn't happen, but if it is non-zero (e.g., 0.5), the "if" executes.  This is because the test expression is evaluated with the same semantics as the "boolean()" function, which interprets the numeric value zero as false and any non-zero numeric value as true.

Comment: But the condition becomes true for Integers but not for decimals.The function number() treats decimals as non integers..Is theres amy other functions which allow interger and decimals?

Comment: @vignesh:  As I said, I tried your code and it did the exact opposite of what you are describing.  Maybe your XSLT processor behaves differently, but if so, I'd call it a bug.  If you look at the XPath standard -- http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions -- you'll see that the number function performs no conversion when passed a number.  It doesn't matter whether that number is an integer or not.

Comment: @vignesh: "The function number() treats decimals as non integers.". What gives you this idea? It's completely wrong. Have you read the response?